# How do I unlock navigation from the origin of an object?

Tags: origin, world, 3d-cursor, navigation

I accidentally locked my view around the origin of my mesh. Now when I zoom it does not zoom in properly, it goes up and down instead of in and out. I can't find the setting where I can unlock it. How do I reset it to center around the *World Origin* or *3D Cursor*.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Blender.SE :). Blender has [this view panel](https://imgur.com/a/0nBX9x9), so maybe you accidentally locked your view there. If it doesn't help, you can [share your file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) and someone can look at it.

Comment: That was it. I was looking in the wrong spot thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hit delete on the numpad, it should reset your viewport to focus around whatever object is selected.